# How to use TFileStream with FILE_SHARE_DELETE?

Tags: delphi, winapi, tfilestream

This QC report say that Delphi doesn't support the file sharing mode [FILE_SHARE_DELETE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=45628

I need to use this mode with TFileStreams - Can anyone think of a straightforward workaround that doesn't involve modifying the library code, or duplicating reams of stuff from the library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The QC report is correct.  `TFileStream` (more specifically, the `SysUtils.FileOpen()` function) does not support `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`.  It only supports `FILE_SHARE_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`.

In order to use sharing rights beyond what `TFileStream` natively supports, you will have to call the Win32 API `CreateFile()` function directly, then you can construct a `THandleStream` object using the handle that `CreateFile()` returns.